# Event loop is closed.Called after closing the discord bot

Tags: python, discord.py

After completion (shutdown) the bot gives an error. Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\Python v 3.10\lib\asyncio\proactor_events.py", line 116, in __del__
    self.close()
  File "E:\Python v 3.10\lib\asyncio\proactor_events.py", line 108, in close
    self._loop.call_soon(self._call_connection_lost, None)
  File "E:\Python v 3.10\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 745, in call_soon
    self._check_closed()
  File "E:\Python v 3.10\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 510, in _check_closed
    raise RuntimeError('Event loop is closed')
RuntimeError: Event loop is closed
Exception ignored in: <function _ProactorBasePipeTransport.__del__ at 0x000001BEC7630310>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\Python v 3.10\lib\asyncio\proactor_events.py", line 116, in __del__
  File "E:\Python v 3.10\lib\asyncio\proactor_events.py", line 108, in close
  File "E:\Python v 3.10\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 745, in call_soon
  File "E:\Python v 3.10\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 510, in _check_closed
RuntimeError: Event loop is closed
```

**My code:**

```
    TOKEN = 'token'
    class MyClient(discord.Client):
        async def on_ready(self):
            print('Logged on as', self.user)

    async def on_message(self, message):
        # don't respond to ourselves
        if message.author == self.user:
            return

        if message.content == 'ping':
            await message.channel.send('pong')


client = MyClient()

client.run(TOKEN)
```

The bot issues such an error after the program is completed. How to fix it?
Solutions like:

```
change token
token is invalid
```

These solutions didn't help me.

The only thing I have improved all the libraries that were. Discord itself, aiohttp and asyncio. But they did not lead to a result. What can such a problem be related to? Bot code, example:

Comment: Please, format your code.

Comment: Please post the *whole* traceback.

Answer (score 2):

This is an aiohttp bug on Windows.
There doesn't seem to be a solution at the moment.

https://github.com/aio-libs/aiohttp/issues/4324